# Populate radio button if checkbox is checked in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to write a JavaScript code where if any of the checkboxes in a certain group are selected, then a radio button should get populated.

Following is the code that I'm working on:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Radio buttons and checkboxes</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <h3>Radio Buttons</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"> Radio 1
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2">Radio 2
        <br>
        <br>

        <h3>Checkbox Groups</h3>

        <h4><u>Group 1</u></h4>
        <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1PD1">G1 PD1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1PD2">G1 PD2</li>
        </ul>
        <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1ID1">G1 ID1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1ID2">G1 ID2</li>
        </ul>

        <h4><u>Group 2</u></h4>
        <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2PD1">G2 PD1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2PD2">G2 PD2</li>
        </ul>
        <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2ID1">G2 ID1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2ID2">G2 ID2</li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I want the JavaScript to do. If any of the checkboxes under `PD` section in Groups 1 and 2 are checked, then the radio button `Radio 1` should get populated. Similarly, if any of the checkboxes under the `ID` section in Groups 1 and 2 are selected, then the radio button `Radio 2` should get populated.

How can I write the jQuery or JavaScript code for this?

### Update

Using @gibberish's answer, I was able to write this JS code:

```
<script>
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var cc = this.className;
if (cc=="pdcb"){
    $('#radio2').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radio1').prop('checked',true);
}else if (cc=="idcb"){
    $('#radio1').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radio2').prop('checked',true);
}
  else
  {
    $('#radio1').prop('checked',false);
    $('#radio2').prop('checked',false);
  }
});
</script>
```

My new question is how do I deselect both the radio buttons if none of the checkboxes aren't checked?

Comment: Could you post what you've done so far in your JS code?

Comment: Why do your radio buttons have different `name` attributes? Radios are supposed to be used in groups, and a group is defined by giving the same `name`...

Comment: @TWFPSP I haven't written any JS code. I'm like totally new to JS.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah! Okay! I'll change the name attribute to having the same one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Attempt to write the code yourself, and ask a question on here if you encounter a specific difficulty.

Comment: Thanks @Natecat. Will keep that in mind. I updated my question with JS code. Could you help me answer my updated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign distinct classnames to your two checkbox groups, it will be easier to determine what to do.

Here is a code sample, both in stack code snippet, and as a [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c4d9mwt6/) *(because they are easier for you to fiddle around with)*

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
 var cc = this.className;
 if (cc=="pdcb"){
  $('#radio2').prop('checked',false);
  $('#radio1').prop('checked',true);
 }else if (cc=="idcb"){
  $('#radio1').prop('checked',false);
  $('#radio2').prop('checked',true);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <h3>Radio Buttons</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"> Radio 1
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2">Radio 2
   <br>
   <br>

   <h3>Checkbox Groups</h3>

   <h4><u>Group 1</u></h4>
   <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD1">G1 PD1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD2">G1 PD2</li>
   </ul>
   <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G1ID1">G1 ID1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G1ID2">G1 ID2</li>
   </ul>

   <h4><u>Group 2</u></h4>
   <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G2PD1">G2 PD1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G2PD2">G2 PD2</li>
   </ul>
   <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G2ID1">G2 ID1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G2ID2">G2 ID2</li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sure, will do. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hey, I updated my question using JS code that I wrote. Could you please help me for the updated question?

Answer (score 1):

This answers the addition to your question.

Note that I used a couple of different methods of selecting the checkboxes / radio buttons. Really, there are two methods: select all at once, and select PD and ID separately.

Then, I showed a couple of different methods for deselecting the radio buttons: all radio buttons on the page, both radio buttons by specifying each ID...

Hopefully, as your project develops, you can review this answer and get new tips.

[This is a useful resource](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) regarding how to poll *(select)* different types of elements (e.g. by ID, by class, as a group, etc). Note that jQuery uses CSS selectors, so learning them is useful twice over.

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
 var cc = this.className;
 if (cc=="pdcb"){
  $('#radio2').prop('checked',false);
  $('#radio1').prop('checked',true);
 }else if (cc=="idcb"){
  $('#radio1').prop('checked',false);
  $('#radio2').prop('checked',true);
 }
   //This is one way (gets them all)
   var num = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
 alert(num);
 //This is another (gets each group)
 var lenPD = $('input[class=pdcb]:checked').length;
 var lenID = $('input[class=idcb]:checked').length;
 alert(lenPD +' / '+ lenID);
  
 //All three below methods work - choose your favorite
 //if (num==0) $('#radio1,#radio2').prop('checked',false);
 //if (lenPD==0 && lenID==0) $('input:radio').prop('checked',false);
 if (lenPD==0 && lenID==0) $('#radio1,#radio2').prop('checked',false);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <h3>Radio Buttons</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"> Radio 1
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2">Radio 2
   <br>
   <br>

   <h3>Checkbox Groups</h3>

   <h4><u>Group 1</u></h4>
   <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD1">G1 PD1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD2">G1 PD2</li>
   </ul>
   <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G1ID1">G1 ID1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G1ID2">G1 ID2</li>
   </ul>

   <h4><u>Group 2</u></h4>
   <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G2PD1">G2 PD1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G2PD2">G2 PD2</li>
   </ul>
   <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G2ID1">G2 ID1</li>
      <li>
         <input class="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G2ID2">G2 ID2</li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

<kbd>[**Updated jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c4d9mwt6/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but is should give you an idea on what to do..
You can also try to add some toggle on the radio button and checkboxes if you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
     $(":checkbox").change(function () {
         if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             var selection = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text();
             if(selection == "PD") 
                 $("#radio1").prop("checked", true);
             else
                 $("#radio2").prop("checked", true)
         }    
     });
});
```

Comment: do some work, a little research and debug it then.. just a few changes and it should work as you need it.

Comment: I don't think someone will come up with everything done for you just like that since you haven't actually tried to write any JS code. This snippet should work for you with a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is calling a function on onclick event passing the radio control id as a parameter. Below your code edited with the function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkRadio(checkBoxId) {
            var radio = document.getElementById(checkBoxId);
            if (!radio.checked)
                radio.checked = true;
        }

    </script>

    <title>Radio buttons and checkboxes</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <h3>Radio Buttons</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"> Radio 1
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2">Radio 2
        <br>
        <br>

        <h3>Checkbox Groups</h3>

        <h4><u>Group 1</u></h4>
        <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1PD1" onclick="checkRadio('radio1')">G1 PD1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1PD2" onclick="checkRadio('radio1')">G1 PD2</li>
        </ul>
        <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1ID1" onclick="checkRadio('radio2')">G1 ID1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G1ID2" onclick="checkRadio('radio2')">G1 ID2</li>
        </ul>

        <h4><u>Group 2</u></h4>
        <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2PD1" onclick="checkRadio('radio1')">G2 PD1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2PD2" onclick="checkRadio('radio1')">G2 PD2</li>
        </ul>
        <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2ID1" onclick="checkRadio('radio2')">G2 ID1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="G2ID2" onclick="checkRadio('radio2')">G2 ID2</li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```